# Can you configure Tripwire to produce an actual diff between modified files

Tags: linux, ids, operating-systems, ubuntu

I'm using the open source version of Tripwire on Ubuntu 22.04. Right now when a file is modified Tripwire will document this in the integrity check with an "Expected" vs "Observed" section, outlining things like md5 change, time change, file size etc..

Is there a way for me to actually see the modification similar to a Linux `diff` command?